# Check whether a user is logged in to Skype or not

Tags: c#, skype

I am working with the Skype API. When my application starts I check to see whether Skype is actually running.

```
foreach (Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("skype"))
{
    return true;
}
```

Now I want to check whether a user has logged in to Skype or not. How can I check this?

Comment: Well... So far you are not really using anything from Skype API. Have you checked the documentation or what is exposed in the API?

Comment: @pwn building on @Marc's answer, use this `bool userLoggedIn = skype.CurrentUserStatus != TUserStatus.cusLoggedOut;`

Answer (score 4):

Downloaded the Skype API to check... Because curiosity. Actually surprised how much stuff is exposed.

```
Skype skype = new Skype();
// Return true if Skype is running.
if (!skype.Client.IsRunning) 
    return;

// User is not logged in.
if (skype.CurrentUserStatus == TUserStatus.cusLoggedOut)
    return;

// Friends
foreach(User user in skype.Friends) 
{
    if (user.OnlineStatus == TOnlineStatus.olsOnline)
    { /*Insert what you want...*/ }

}
```

Note that Skype first ask you if you want to let a specific plugin access it.

Comment: @Jutras I want to check if anyone already is logged in to skype OR not?

Comment: Any as in... Anyone in the whole Skype database or anyone in your friend list? Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: @Jutras Suppose skype is running on computer,I want to check whether anypne is logged into skype or is it running without anyone logged in

Comment: You can check if the process is running, like you did, or check the property "skype.Client.IsRunning". After that, skype.Friends return a "Not Attached." exception if there is no valid account logged in.

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras I think it simply check if skype runing or not on your system.It does't check user logged in or not

Comment: @Gurbax: I edited my comment. skype.Friends throws "Not Attached." if no valid account is logged in.

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras I think he wants to know if any user is logged into Skype not if any of the user's friends are logged in (more like `skype.CurrentUserStatus != TUserStatus.cusLoggedOut;`)